# Work permit for J2 minor dependents (under 7 years old)

Tags: children, j-visa, non-residents, work-permit

I work in the US as a researcher under J1 visa. I would like to know if it is possible to get the work permit (EAD) for my J2 minor children (3 and 5 years old). I would like to get the SSN for them in order to claime the child tax credit and lower my taxes.

I know that there is no age restriction for the EAD, but does it also apply for J2 toddlers?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can my J-2 children get SSNs to be claimed as dependents on a tax return?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/24158/can-my-j-2-children-get-ssns-to-be-claimed-as-dependents-on-a-tax-return)

Comment: A "job" that a toddler or baby could do would be modeling or acting. Instructions for the form do say a parent or guardian can sign for a minor.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your help. Actually I already read the link. I consulted an attorney who claims that there is no age restriction for an EAD, but this may not work for J2 dependents. However, he wasn't able to justify this claim with the proof

Comment: @Abateon proof of what? We discussed that in the other question, I was skeptical about it too but the instructions seem to be pretty clear.